# Synonym request: pugjs > jade

Tags: support, status-completed, synonym-request

I can't suggest it myself.
Please add [pugjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pugjs) as a synonym to [jade](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jade).

To avoid any [confusion](https://github.com/expressjs/express/issues/2952) someone should probably edit the wiki as well.

**cf https://github.com/pugjs/pug/issues/2184**

Comment: @ZachSaucier no clearly you didn't read this question and the comments. If anything since I asked it first, the other question could be considered a duplicate.

Comment: The other question is higher quality than this one IMO, thus I voted to CV this one

Comment: @ZachSaucier interesting but the community disagrees.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After speaking with the Pug project maintainer ([ForbesLindesay](https://stackoverflow.com/users/272958/forbeslindesay)) today, I've merged [jade](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jade) into [pug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pug), and added a synonym from the former to the latter.

Comment: You might find [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/310106/can-we-repurpose-the-jade-tag-for-the-jade-community) interesting.

Answer (score 6):

The library name is actually pug, not pugjs, so the tag should be named [pug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pug).

I think that [jade](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jade) should be renamed to [pug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pug) and [jade](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jade) should be made a synonym to [pug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pug).

Comment: I disagree [tag:jade] is well known and should remain the master tag. You could request that to be reversed in 2 or 3 years if it becomes necessary. pug or pugjs—whatever the name—one or both must be added as a synonym.

Comment: @Knu But jade is being renamed to pug everywhere. It shouldn't be referred to as jade anymore.

Comment: @Knu The synonym direction (in my personal opinion) should reflect the canonical name. The autocomplete will work either way, it doesn't matter.

Comment: The library name is being changed to pug everywhere.  Jade should redirect to pug, not the other way round.  I would think as the maintainer of the library in question, my opinion would be sufficient to persuade someone to make this change.