# Can we repurpose the [jade] tag for the JADE community?

Tags: discussion, status-declined, tag-disambiguation

I recently registered on Stack Overflow in an effort to try and facilitate better discussion between developers in the JADE community.

To clarify (as I know there's been confusion before), I'm referring to developers around the world using the platform created by [those people](http://www.jadeworld.com) who had the trademark forcing the [jade -> pug rename](https://github.com/pugjs/pug/issues/2184) in 2016.

During the last conference for developers using JADE, issues around the current forums we use were raised (they're less than ideal), and it was proposed we switch to using Stack Overflow instead. As JADE is a platform that can co-exist with others, this makes a lot of sense for us, as problems we encounter might be more to do with how we're using another technology that others here know more about.

For those that had to accommodate the rename to pug, as a developer who struggles to come up with good names for my own projects (that no-one else has already), I'm certainly sympathetic to what happened back then; but I hope it's water under the bridge now and our community won't be held in disrepute as a result.

As someone who wants to help improve collaboration amongst JADE developers, I'm here today to ask if we can use the 'jade' tag going forward?

This is currently set up as a tag synonym that redirects to pug, but I'm hoping the wider Stack Overflow community would now be happy to break the link between the two, and welcome a new community of developers using it for the thing that has the trademark.

Obviously, being a newly registered user, I couldn't do this myself, nor could I figure out how to contact the user who created the synonym to discuss privately .. so hope this public request is welcomed in the spirit for which it's being requested, to foster better collaboration with my peers :)

I would be happy to write up an introduction for the tag, including a reference to pug to maintain clarity about how it was renamed.

**MIGRATED:** This question was [originally asked](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/310106/can-we-repurpose-the-jade-tag-for-the-jade-community) on the Stack Exchange meta site by mistake.  I recommend referring to the original comments which discussed some initial points of view about this.

Comments [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/320138/synonym-request-pugjs-jade) also highlight how pug shouldn't be referred to as jade anymore; alongside a suggested plan for reversing synonyms created at that time if required after 2-3 years.

**EXAMPLES:** Since asking this question, a developer has [asked a question to get us started](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50593615/remove-an-invalid-reference-from-a-collection-in-jade), and has also [found another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21226127/jade-database-and-php) that had been asked previously in 2014.

Comment: rene is right that this would require a lot of editing. Even limiting it to questions there's still over 4000 [posts tagged with pug but use the word Jade](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=jade%20%5bpug%5d%20is%3aquestion). The newest question in those results was posted May 10th, 2018 so there would likely need to be a lot editing after any cleanup effort.

Comment: @BSMP I wouldn't expect all questions to be edited retrospectively, as that's how they were asked.  The critical thing is how they're tagged and asked/fixed going forward.  Looking at recent examples, it appears pug users know about the name change, but some use pug/jade terminology in case those reading aren't aware.  Questions being raised like this are in decline, with [759 in 2016](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=jade+%5Bpug%5D+is%3Aquestion+created%3A2016), [389 in 2017](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=jade+%5Bpug%5D+is%3Aquestion+created%3A2017), and only 81 so far this year.

Comment: I'm not as active as I used to be on the site but if the community decides to do this, I can help with tag edits.

Comment: "*issues around our current forums were raised (they're less than ideal), and it was proposed we switch to using Stack Overflow instead*" Please read this first: [Can I support my product on this site?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/product-support).

Comment: @gre_gor Poor choice of words on my part, they're not "our" forums as I don't work for the company who created the product.  I've edited the question to better reflect this.

Comment: @duplode - If removing the synonym means old questions originally tagged as [jade] will be treated as that again, that's a breaking change, and why we couldn't re-purpose any tag.  However, when searching by either tag, the same number of results are returned, with pug being stated.  This seems to coincide with comments about [tags being remapped](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/pug/synonyms), which I'd interpreted as updating questions retrospectively to fix the tags permanently, rather than leaving query & display logic with the overhead of handle synonyms indefinitely. Have I got that wrong?

Comment: @duplode I'm confused. Where do you get that number from? Because if all we do is break the synonym I don't know where those 4000 questions will come from as [that info is no longer in the database on the posts or tags table](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/852233). At best you could reconstruct based on posthistory but I don't recall that ever happened. Based on posthistory for questions I can still see it would be 149 posts at most. What am I missing?

Comment: @rene The 4000 figure comes from reading BSMP's first comment too quickly. It is good news that is not the case :)

Comment: @Kevin Synonimising does preserve the old tag below the surface. However, another look at how the synonym proposal was handled shows that [\[jade\] was *merged* into \[pug\] just before the synonym was created](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/339166/2751851), which means [questions from before the merger won't be affected](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/260237/242059). So the situation is indeed better than what I made it look like in that comment.

Comment: @duplode The final statement in the second link states: _"If foo is also made a synonym of bar, then when this synonym is removed no question will have the foo tag."_ - So nothing should have the underlying [jade] tag?

Comment: @duplode Using an alternative tag is an option (rene also suggested this), but there's still a risk of confusion arising while [jade] is setup as a synonym to [pug].  We could end up with a few variations, but the natural tendency would be to use [jade] as that's how we've always known it - which means they'll get tagged as [pug] under the hood! Fundamentally, the question is about whether or not we can re-purpose the tag, for which there doesn't seem to be a technical reason against it. But, to avoid mix-ups (and misuse of a trademarked name), is blacklisting [jade] a more feasible option?

Comment: @Kevin "So nothing should have the underlying [jade] tag?" -- Yup. Sounds like I have been wrong all along :)

Comment: Blacklisting isn't a good fit, as [that is only meant for tags with no reasonable use cases](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/295148/242059). Another thing to note is that tags are only created after there are questions that need them. That being so, getting some on-topic questions about JADE posted here, perhaps under a provisional tag, will strengthen your case. If need be, you can draw attention to this request once that is done, by editing this question or posting a self-answer pointing to them.

Comment: @duplode OK - Overall, the basic question has now been answered (it _can_ be done), on the proviso we first establish the need using a provisional tag to demonstrate it's needed.  If you or rene would like to submit this as an answer for others to refer to if they get into a weird scenarios like this (where preferred names point to what are now unrelated products), I'd be happy to mark it as the accepted answer.  In the meantime, I've [informed](https://forums.jadeworld.com/viewtopic.php?f=11&t=2288) other JADE developers, so there's a plan for when/ we start using SO. Thanks for your help :)

Comment: @rene Thanks for your help :) ... As above, if you want to submit the overall answer, happy to accept it (assuming duplode doesn't beat you to it).

Comment: @Kevin Answer posted. (Extra advice from our fellow Meta denizens is, as usual, most welcome.)

Comment: The question can't be understood unless you define the jargon: 1) JADE = "JAVA Agent DEvelopment Framework" (open-source P2P agent platform) 2) "Pug (formerly known pre-2016 as Jade) is a robust, elegant and feature rich template engine for Node.js." Are you suggesting renaming from 2) -> 1) ?

Comment: @smci I'm suggesting the jade tag be used for the software which has the trademark (leading to the pug rename).  I'd intentionally phrased the first link 'those people' to match the reference within the pug issue about the rename (second link) to help illustrate which JADE I was referring to.

Comment: You now have [a sample question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50593615/2751851), which looks fine to me. You might want to mention it in this Meta question, as I suggested in my answer, though it will also be okay if you'd rather wait until there are a few more questions under [jade-platform].

Comment: @duplode - Yes, I'll do that now.  I'd been waiting to see who else might jump in and ask something.  Interestingly enough, [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21226127/jade-database-and-php) was found & tagged from 2014.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suggest having a few questions (or at least one) about JADE posted here, as [tags are created when they have to be applied](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/252944/2751851). *Make sure they are [on-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)*, so that they actually support your case for repurposing the tag.

Once the questions are posted, edit this Meta question to add links to them. This should be enough to get things rolling. Note that the removal of the synonym [can only be performed by a moderator](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/358379/2751851). If you mention the questions here, they are well received and yet, after a few days, nothing happens, you can ask the moderators to have a look by casting a custom flag (Flag >> In need of moderator intervention) on this Meta question.

Once the synonym is removed, one important thing to do is to [create an appropriate tag wiki for [jade]](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/214337/242059). In particular, the tag wiki excerpt should contain usage guidance, which in this case will likely look like this:

> Questions about JADE, a [objective characterisation of JADE in a handful of words]. For questions about the JavaScript template engine formerly known as Jade, use the [pug] tag instead.

P.S.: Previously, I had suggested you to use a provisional tag such as [jade-platform], or whatever you consider appropriate; however, 1500 rep is needed to create a tag, and so you won't be able to do that by yourself right now. Instead, I (or someone else reading this) can add the provisional tag once you add links to the questions here. Once the synonym is removed, switching them to [jade] will be straightfoward.

Answer (score 4):

I don't really...see much in the way of content on your site that tells me that it makes sense to have a tag here.  I don't know enough about the product or products you offer, and as such, I can't tell if your questions would be objectively on-topic here.

[There are some guidelines available on Meta](https://stackoverflow.com/help/product-support) about how one could possibly support their product here, but I would strongly discourage you from doing so right now for a few reasons:

- It's unclear if developers are actually asking questions about it (if they are, I can stand corrected; please link me to such questions)
- Your account alone isn't suitable to moderate the tag; you don't have enough reputation to even do the most basic form of moderation, which is the downvote

Comment: [This page](https://www.jadeworld.com/solutions-for/dev-partners/) makes it seem JADE Platform is a development environment of some sort, and so on-topic questions are at least conceivable.

Comment: @Makoto I'm not employed by the company who created the JADE software, rather a developer who depends on it.  We've traditionally not asked questions here because we've a bad culture of asking questions internally or trying to use old forums which aren't really fit for purpose anymore - Hence there was the suggestion we make a switch to using Stack Overflow so we can be more open and share information between companies using JADE, which I'm now following up on to see how feasible that is.

Comment: The most basic forms of moderation are "participate on meta" and "flag". Very powerful, if you use correctly.