# Attempting to create tag [m-files], conflicting with tag [matlab]

Tags: support, tags

I was trying to tag a question with a new tag [m-files] and get the following error/notification:

> You are attempting to create a tag m-files; however the tag [matlab] already exists! If you think this new tag should be allowed, raise it on meta.

The question I was trying to edit was [MFiles API setting propertyValue](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43506014/1288184). In this case M-Files is an ECM software and has nothing to do with MATLAB. (more specifically the question is about the [M-Files COM API](https://developer.m-files.com/APIs/COM-API/)). Quick googling shows other SO questions related to M-Files software although many MATLAB questions use the term "m-files" also.

(Disclosure: I currently **do** work for M-Files.)

Comment: The tag [tag:m-file] already exists, its a synonym of matlab, look at the right-hand side here: https://stackoverflow.com/tags/matlab/synonyms. Are you sure you're creating `m-files` (plural), not `m-file`?

Comment: Using a company name as a tag has never been terribly popular.  Consider [mfiles-api].

Comment: @GerardoFurtado I did try adding [m-files] but the synonym check probably checks for plural endings also...

Comment: @HansPassant thanks for the suggestion. M-Files is currently both the name of the software and the company (think of tags [sap] and [dropbox] for example). The downside of having just mfiles-api is that there are other parts of M-Files which might need tags in the future. For example javascript-based [UIX framework](https://developer.m-files.com/Frameworks/User-Interface-Extensibility-Framework/).

Comment: I agree with Hans here, if there is a framework related question, then [tag:mfiles-framework], or [tag:mfiles-ui] would be fine. Though it is not wrong to create company named tags (especially when the company provides just one product), it has been preferred to create more product specific tags (like for example, [jetbrains-ide] instead of [jetbrains]).

Comment: @BhargavRao ok, good to know, I understand the reasoning and conform with this then. In this case the M-Files **would** have only one main product: software called M-Files which consists of components like M-Files server and M-Files desktop. But if more specific tags are anyway preferred then let's continue with those. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: Also, if they were to allow you to use [m-files] for your product, we'd get tons of MATLAB questions wrongly tagged with the [m-files] tag. People don't read the tag description, they only pay attention to the name. So it's better if the tag name itself is not ambiguous. Ask the people following the [tag:processing] tag how much fun they have removing that tag from so many [image-processing] questions!

Comment: @BhargavRao Tangential question: was [this request](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/367969/2751851) declined by this reasoning about product specific tags, and/or following Cris Luengo's rationale about mistagging?

Comment: @duplode, neither ... I declined because of the score on the post. It was heavily downvoted indicating that the community was against the request.

Comment: @BhargavRao Oh, that's fine, too. (I just happened to think of that discussion upon reading this question.)