# Do we need both [pug] and [pugjs]?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, synonym-request

The tag for pug is:

> Pug (formerly known as Jade) is a robust, elegant and feature rich
>   template engine for Node.js.

The tag for pugjs is:

> pugjs is the Github organization which creates the "Pug" (previously
>   known as "Jade") Node.js templating library.

The questions tagged with pugjs are all about the template engine, as you would probably guess.

I don't think that we need both pug and pugjs tags.  [This meta question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/320138/synonym-request-pugjs-jade) correctly says that the official name of the project is pug and not pugjs.

Should we make pugjs a synonym of pug?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, we don't need them.

The synonym for [pug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pug) <- [pugjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pugjs) was already proposed on Jan 17 '17 at 11:05, but unfortunately did not find much support.

I've now approved the synonym proposal and they're now synonyms. Given that the other linked post clearly mentions that the name is pug and not pugjs, I've synonymized it in that direction.

Comment: I did search for pugjs before posting this and that proposal didn't show up.  Strange.  No matter what, thanks for fixing this.